# Can't make Home Sharing work on my iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, wifi, sharing

I've got the latest iTunes on my Mac [10.2.1(1)], I've downloaded iOS4.3 to my iPad, so I've got all the software that should be necessary, right?

My Apple I.D. and password have both been correctly entered on the Mac and the iPad. Home Sharing has been activated on the Mac, but the iPad can't see it.

Last night I was actually able to get it to function for a couple of hours, but this morning it was gone again. And even when it was working last night I could go to the "sharing" preferences pane in iTunes on my Mac and the status would read: Status: On, no users connected.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. All I had to do was restart my wireless router. Duh.

I didn't think it was at fault because I was getting a full signal to both the Mac and the iPad. But that was just the trick.

Works great now.

Answer (score 0):

Router troubles, huh?

My iTunes sharing difficulties arose from the way I was moving libraries around:

[Home sharing on iOS may not display some libraries](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2011031019381274)

"This happens if you have duplicated your library by copying ~/Music/iTunes to one or more machine from another machine. Those libraries will be sharing the same library id and therefore IOs 4.3 is not able to distinguish them..."